# Azure Marketplace Partner For Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

We planning to sell our Web Application to Azure Marketplace and regarding on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partners/ under Web Application but it leads to the Windows Web Gallery which is my thought for the Web Platform Installer only.

Sorry my question is
"Does Windows Web Gallery connect to Azure Gallery? Sorry for asking this I've really confused with those two."

Please guide me if I am wrong

Advance Thank you

Comment: I am also searching for this and could not find any. I found this question asked yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346736/web-app-onboarding-to-azure-web-marketplace As your question is posted on Feb, did you get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to release into the Azure Marketplace to sell you application as a SAAS. The right spot would be [Microsoft Azure Certified](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partner-program/) the first option.