# Web app onboarding to Azure Web Marketplace

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-marketplace

We checked this documentation - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/26/onboarding-to-azure-web-marketplace on how to onboard our web apps in the Azure marketplace and also the GitHub link - https://github.com/SunBuild/web-app-marketplace

We have contacted MSFT on how to host our application which has an API and WCF applications as sub-applications.

MSFT replied that sub applications are not currently supported in through this onboarding model.

So, we are trying to onboard the three applications individually and link them in the Azure marketplace. We are not sure whether this will work or if this is possible.

In the sample applications in the GitHub link - https://github.com/SunBuild/web-app-marketplace, they have a hosting plan JSON file for the web app resource. Can we link the applications using this hosting plan JSON file?

We could not find any information or definition related to this hosting plan file - https://github.com/SunBuild/web-app-marketplace/blob/master/WebApp-SQLDatabase/DeploymentTemplates/Website_NewHostingPlan_SQL_NewDB-Default.json

Does anyone tried this before or know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> sub applications are not currently supported in through this onboarding model.

From [the documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/26/onboarding-to-azure-web-marketplace/), we could know if **web app need Virtual application setting to be configured for web app**, we will not be able to on board the application.

> we are trying to onboard the three applications individually and link them in the Azure marketplace. We are not sure whether this will work or if this is possible.

In my view, if you on board these application individually, it may not enable us to bundle multi individual applications to make them link with each other. You could contact with Azure marketplace support team.

> We could not find any information or definition related to this hosting plan file - https://github.com/SunBuild/web-app-marketplace/blob/master/WebApp-SQLDatabase/DeploymentTemplates/Website_NewHostingPlan_SQL_NewDB-Default.json

In the link you posted, we could find that it is an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template that is used to define resources you want to deploy. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) explained about the Azure Resource Manager template, please refer to it.